# Keyhole contour integration of $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{1/2}\log(z)}{(1+z)^2}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm trying to use a contour integral to integrate $$K = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{1/2}\log(z)}{(1+z)^2}dz$$

I used the "squaring to log" trick with a keyhole contour on the postive real axis. I must be bungling something though.

When I compute the residue of $\frac{z^{1/2}\log(z)^2}{(1+z)^2}$ at $-1$, I obtain $2\pi i(2\pi + \frac{i\pi^2}{2})$ (obtained by taking the derivative of the numerator and evaluating at $-1$). On the otherhand, when I simplify $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{z^{1/2}\log(z)^2}{(1+z)^2}-\frac{z^{1/2}(\log(z)+2\pi i)^2}{(1+z)^2}dz = \\-4\pi i K+2\pi^3$$

I suspect something is wrong because the real parts of this don't match my residue computation.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We provide support for  the main steps. Introducing $\mathrm{Log}(z)$,
the branch with argument in $[0,2\pi)$ we integrate

$$f(z) =
\exp((1/2)\mathrm{Log}(z)) \frac{\mathrm{Log}(z)}{(1+z)^2}$$

along a keyhole contour with the slit on the positive real axis.
We get in the limit above the slit

$$K = \int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}\frac{\log(x)}{(1+x)^2} \; dx.$$

Below the slit we find

$$\int_\infty^0 \exp(\pi i)
\sqrt{x} \frac{\log(x)+2\pi i}{(1+x)^2} \; dx
= \int_0^\infty
\sqrt{x} \frac{\log(x)+2\pi i}{(1+x)^2} \; dx
\\ = K + 2\pi i \int_0^\infty
\sqrt{x} \frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \; dx = K + 2\pi i J.$$

We have the two contributions separated into real and imaginary parts,
so  we  just  need  to  compute  the  residue  at  $z=-1$  of  $f(z).$
Differentiating we find

$$\frac{1}{2z} \exp((1/2)\mathrm{Log}(z)) \mathrm{Log}(z)
+ \frac{1}{z} \exp((1/2)\mathrm{Log}(z)).$$

Evaluate at $z=-1$ to get

$$-\frac{1}{2} \exp((1/2)\pi i) (\pi i) - \exp((1/2)\pi i)
= \frac{\pi}{2} - i.$$

With $K$ and $J$ real we collect the contributions to obtain

$$2K + 2\pi i J = 2\pi i \times \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - i\right)
= \pi^2 i + 2\pi.$$

This means that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
K = \pi \quad\text{and}\quad J = \frac{\pi}{2}.}$$

The required ML estimates for  the circular components go through with
$\lim_{R\to\infty}  2\pi R  \times \sqrt{R}  \log(R)/(1+R)^2 =  0$ and
$\lim_{\epsilon\to   0}    2\pi   \epsilon    \times   \sqrt{\epsilon}
\log(\epsilon) /(1+\epsilon)^2 = 0.$

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with branch points it is not a bad idea to enforce some substitution in order to simplify the problem. By letting $z=w^2$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{z}\log(z)}{(1+z)^2}\,dz = 4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{w^2 \log(w) }{(1+w^2)^2}\,dw=4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{w^2 \log(w) }{(1+w^2)^2}\,dw+4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log(w) }{(1+w^2)^2}\,dw $$
and it is enough to compute
$$ 4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-w^2}{(1+w^2)^2}\left(-\log w\right)\,dw=4\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n(2n+1)\int_{0}^{1}w^{2n}(-\log w)\,dw $$
which is just
$$ 4\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1} = 4\arctan(1) = \color{red}{\pi}.$$
This shows that we may avoid the hunting phase for the suitable contour.
Feyman's trick and the (inverse) Laplace transform allow to do the same in many other situations.

Comment: 1. how did you get to the second step in the second line? 2. Perhaps there are other ways, but I have to use contours! Is there a way to adapt this argument?

Comment: @yoshi: it is not difficult to compute the Taylor series of $\frac{1-u}{(1+u)^2}$ at $u=0$ from the Taylor series of $\frac{1+u}{(1-u)^2}$ and stars and bars, for instance.